# How do I print the contents of a for loop using (1..10).each?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to print out the contents of my `for` loop on the web page as an output from 1 to 10.

index.html.erb:

```
<%= (1..10).each do |i|
  print i
end %>
```

webpage output:

```
1..10
```

Current terminal and desired output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to print this out in Rails (per your comment), try this:

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <%= i %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: So if you were to want to add these items to a list you would use:

```
<ol>
  <% (1..10).each do |i| %>
    <li><%= i %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
  <%= i %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a Webpage in HTML, right?

Try this:

```
<%= (1..10).map { |i| "<p>#{i}</p>" }.join.html_safe %>
```

Or this

```
<%= (1..10).map { |i| "#{i}\n" }.join %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this:

```
<%= (1..10).each do |i| 
  puts i
end %>
```

I found "[puts vs print in ruby](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattberther.com%2F2009%2F02%2F11%2Fputs-vs-print-in-ruby&ei=ye_vTtCQJKz_sQLDzfzKCQ&usg=AFQjCNH5di7s7XMD44twW913Ok7qb-y_xA&sig2=-PoFtB2xWUuZoy8Qnuun-Q)" of some help for this question:

Comment: I've already tried that.  It doesn't work.  It produces the same result as using print

Comment: what console are you using?  I try that code in irb and it works alright.

Comment: Using the rails console in my mac os terminal, using puts prints it out the way I want it to print out, but using that same exact code in my index.html.erb produces just 1..10 on the webpage

Comment: Oh, is it because rails is ignoring white space?  Do you need to add a <br /> in there??  I haven't used Rails much.

Comment: Pay attention to the return value:

=> 1..10